# Filter two tabs with the same data simultaneously in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, simultaneous

I've been looking for an answer to this and while I have found similar situations, the solutions provided did not help my current situation.

I have a workbook that features two tabs that houses the same data. One tab is used as a "control" tab, the other one is used as an editable one so that users can change information and when they send submit the workbook, our database specialist can quickly find the altered values.

The way this works is that the editable worksheet has a conditional format linking back to the "control" worksheet (i.e. A1 on the editable worksheet = A1 on the 'control' worksheet, A34 = A34, so on and so fourth).

The issue is that our users want to be able to be able to sort out their projects only, and when they do that the control and editable sheets no longer will mirror one another and the conditional format activates on the entire set of data.

I'm looking for a way that a user can sort on the editable sheet, and the "control" sheet will automatically do the same sort to maintain uniformity and thus the conditional format will only activate when an actual cell value is changed.

Comment: You might be able to detect filter change on the worksheet, and apply the same filter to the second. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler

Comment: MatthewD , Okay that is pretty interesting. So following the link (and the link in within the link) I didn't see of a way to pull the results of the filter, unless I am reading it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  But wouldn't the result be what is left on the sheet. Worst case you could loop the sheet checking if each row is hidden. If so hid it on the next sheet.

Comment: Ah i see. So this probably wouldnt work for me. I already have a button that imports the schema (and copies it into the control and editable tabs) and then Hides columns (as the users do not need to see them and having them may confuse them).

I guess maybe I could create a button that would essentially run "Record Macro" and call the button "Sort table", doing so would apply the filter and then record the users inputs, and then when the user is done performing the sorts, they would have to hit the STOP SORT button and that would trigger to end the recorded macro and run it on the control tab

Comment: It might be easier to give them a form with checkboxes or a combobox so they could define their filter and hit apply rather than having them use the excel filter through the worksheet.  That way when they hit apply you could apply the filter to both sheets based on what they selected on the form.

Comment: I rather use [Worksheet.Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.14).aspx) to record changes. Or even the builtin **[Track Changes](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15)** feature.