# Filters on seperate sheet that shows specific columns from table excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set an example is below first row is headings

```
Name, Sex, Ethnicity, ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
ExampleA, M, A, A, B, B
ExampleB, M, C, B, B, A
ExampleC, F, D, A, B, B
ExampleD, F, A, A, B, B
ExampleE, M, A, A, B, B
```

I want to create on a separate sheet a summary table of just names that allows filters that automatically update the summary table.

For example if Sex: M is filtered then only the males names are listed in the table below.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

1. Detect when the filter has changed. The solution is not very simple, but it is doable. See [Excel VBA Filter Change event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler) .
2. Select intended cells and copy.  *Goto -> Special -> Visible cells only*. Copy, and paste where you want. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-visible-cells-only-6e3a1f01-2884-4332-b262-8b814412847e). VBA code for this is found [here](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008524_Selecting_Visible_Cells_in_a_Macro.html).