# how to add color to the filtered column while applying filter using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to work on an excel sheet while will return a particular color while applying a filter.
for eg when I apply filter on an active column, it should return green. and when I remove the filter green should vanish.

I have been using the below VBA code but does not do the work as the previously applied filter columns are still appearing as green which create confusion.

```
Sub ColorFilterColumn()
    Dim flt As Filter
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rTemp As Range
    Dim bFullCol As Boolean

    ' Set as True if you want entire column shaded
    bFullCol = True

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        iCol = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Column
        lRow = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Row
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each flt In ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters
            If bFullCol Then
                Set rTemp = Cells(lRow, iCol).EntireColumn
            Else
                Set rTemp = Cells(lRow, iCol)
            End If

            If flt.On Then
                rTemp.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                rTemp.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End If

            Set rTemp = Nothing
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Next flt
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Three questions for you. `1` Are there any colors in the cells when there is no filter `2` The filtered cells should be colored green? `3` The moment filter is removed that green color should disappear?

Comment: Hi Siddarth,1) No colors in the cell 2)That's right 3)yes. But now when I remove the filter green appears. but when I run the macro again it disappears

Comment: You have to remove the colour when the autofilter is manually removed. Write a code in the worksheet which captures the event when the filter is manually removed. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler) will get you started