# filter selection prompt by user

Tags: vba

i want to run my code such that it can pause and allow user to filter a column and then the code continues to run. Is this possible?

I thought of using inputbox to prompt user to key in the name. However, this is not feasible because user may not be able to remember the exact name. It will be more convenient for the user to look at the drop down list and select the name he wants to filter.
Please advice me how can this be done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop a VBA macro to wait until an action was done within Excel.

I see the following possibilities:

**a)** Create a small userform showing a dropdown. If you show that form modal (that is the default), the macro will pause and wait until the form is closed. However, you will need to implement code to fill up the dropdown and to set the filter by code.

**b)** End your macro and implement an event that fires when the user changes the filter. There is no *"On filter change"*-event in Excel, but there is a work around: [Excel VBA Filter Change event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler). Put the second part of your code into a separate sub and call that from the event handler.

Comment: For option (A) , I do have a userform that has combo box with dropdown list. And yes i am able to open the form(e.g UserForm1.Show vbModeless) while my main code is running. However, after the userform is opened, the code did not pause but continue to run. Hence, i am not able to make selection in the combo box. 

How can i resolve this?

Comment: If you show the form modeless, the code does not stop. You need to show the form modal (use parameter `vbModal` or omit the parameter). Modal means that the user cannot do anything within Excel before the form is closed, and the code will stop.